# php error log is not writing out to file

Tags: php, apache, error-logging, error-log, server-configuration

I've been having issues with a php server recently, where the error log is not being written out anywhere.

My current php.ini configuration looks like this (Automatically Generated by 1and1.co.uk)

```
[PHP]
tidy.clean_output = Off
mysql.allow_persistent = On
mysql.max_links = -1
safe_mode_allowed_env_vars = PHP_
session.bug_compat_42 = Off
mysql.connect_timeout = 60
max_allowed_packet = 150
register_argc_argv = Off
open_basedir = "/var/www/vhosts/server/:/tmp/"
session.name = PHPSESSID
session.hash_function = 0
magic_quotes_runtime = Off
log_errors_max_len = 1024
mssql.secure_connection = Off
pgsql.max_links = -1
variables_order = "GPCS"
sybct.allow_persistent = On
max_input_time = 60
odbc.max_links = -1
session.save_handler = files
error_log = /var/www/vhosts/server/tmp/php_err.log
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
pgsql.auto_reset_persistent = Off
session.cache_expire = 180
error_reporting = "E-ALL"
safe_mode_gid = Off
auto_prepend_file =
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
sybct.min_client_severity = 10
pgsql.max_persistent = -1
auto_globals_jit = On
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl = 86400
allow_url_fopen = On
smtp_port = 25
register_globals = Off
display_startup_errors = Off
user_dir =
mssql.min_error_severity = 10
mysqli.max_links = -1
default_socket_timeout = 60
session.serialize_handler = php
session.hash_bits_per_character = 5
unserialize_callback_func =
default_mimetype = "text/html"
magic_quotes_gpc = Off
safe_mode_include_dir =
max_execution_time = 30
mail.add_x_header = On
upload_max_filesize = 20M
register_long_arrays = Off
safe_mode = off
zlib.output_compression = Off
safe_mode_protected_env_vars = LD_LIBRARY_PATH
odbc.max_persistent = -1
mssql.compatability_mode = Off
file_uploads = On
mysqli.reconnect = Off
session.cookie_domain =
mssql.allow_persistent = On
mysql.max_persistent = -1
mssql.max_links = -1
session.use_trans_sid = 0
mysql.default_socket =
mysqli.default_pw =
odbc.defaultbinmode = 1
sybct.max_persistent = -1
output_buffering = 4096
doc_root =
log_errors = on
mysql.default_host =
request_order = "GP"
display_errors = On
mysqli.default_socket =
safe_mode_exec_dir =
html_errors = Off
session.entropy_length = 0
y2k_compliance = On
post_max_size = 8M
asp_tags = On
memory_limit = "1.5G"
short_open_tag = On
session.use_only_cookies = 1
SMTP = localhost
precision = 14
session.bug_compat_warn = Off
sybct.min_server_severity = 10
mssql.min_message_severity = 10
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.save_path = "/var/lib/php/session"
session.gc_probability = 1
allow_url_include = Off
mysqli.default_host =
mysqli.default_user =
session.referer_check =
pgsql.log_notice = 0
mysql.default_port =
odbc.defaultlrl = 4096
pgsql.ignore_notice = 0
mysql.trace_mode = Off
engine = On
odbc.allow_persistent = On
track_errors = Off
pgsql.allow_persistent = On
session.auto_start = 0
auto_append_file =
disable_classes =
mysql.default_password =
url_rewriter.tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry"
allow_call_time_pass_reference = Off
ignore_repeated_source = Off
sql.safe_mode = Off
session.cookie_path = /
session.entropy_file =
expose_php = On
report_memleaks = On
session.gc_divisor = 1000
mssql.max_persistent = -1
serialize_precision = 100
odbc.check_persistent = On
sybct.max_links = -1
define_syslog_variables = Off
session.cookie_httponly =
session.cache_limiter = nocache
enable_dl = Off
ignore_repeated_errors = Off
mysqli.default_port = 3306
disable_functions =
magic_quotes_sybase = Off
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled = 1
session.use_cookies = 1
mysql.default_user =
implicit_flush = Off
bcmath.scale = 0
```

I have checked `phpinfo()` and it is linking to the correct php.ini file, and the web user also has write access to the folder which the log file is directed to be logging to.

On top of this, even when I add `ini_set('display_errors', '1');` it still does not either display, nor log the php scripting errors.

Is there something that I am missing with regards having the php errors log out to file somewhere??

I usually access the logs via `tail -f /var/log/httpd/error_log`
so could this maybe be an issue with my Apache Configuration?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible that a custom error handler is used? Did you try an empty php file with just some `echo 1/0;` line?

Comment: And just to make sure, you know that your config is using /var/www/vhosts/server/tmp/php_err.log and not your usual apache log?

Comment: Yes, I do indeed ;) I put the filename in there purposely to have an absolute filepath to navigate to, as well as the usual /var/log/httpd/error_log @ToBe Please can you explain what you mean by an _empty php file with just some echo 1/0;_ ? do you mean the php.ini file? or just a normal php file on the server?